# How to change the favicon in Joomla

Tags: templates

So I am new to Joomla, and am trying to change our favicon. I already have a 16*16 .ico image, but can't figure out how to use it. I don't know how to use cPanel. What do I do?

Answer (score 5):

The `favicon.ico` file needs to be copied to the default template folder. For example, if you are using the Protostar template, the file would be copied to:

```
/templates/protostar/favicon.ico
```

You might also wish to copy the `favicon.ico` file to the root folder of your website e.g. `/public_html` or similar as [this can improve performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8765472/1983389) slightly and reduce error messages being logged when the file is not found.

When you log in to cPanel, look for File Manager which you can use to upload files to the desired locations.

Alternatively, you could use an FTP client (the credentials are usually the same as cPanel credentials) to upload the files.

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on the template you're using.
For most cases all you need to do is upload the favicon.ico file into the root directory your website (it can be: public_html , htdocs , httpdocs etc.)
Sometimes you need to copy the .ico file also into the template directory, which is under: `/public_html/templates/your_template_name/`
Please use browser tool "Inspect Element" and determine where you should put that file.
You can always provide us with your site name and we will be able to check this for you.

Comment: It does depend on the template but the usual location for the favicon file is the template folder: https://docs.joomla.org/changing_the_site_favicon

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided by Neil is my vote for "The Answer" - but if you're looking for a more robust favicon option, you can do so with this favicon generator:

http://www.favicon-generator.org/

It will provide you with a favicon file, and meta data to include in your header. You just need to adjust the file path accordingly.  The advantage of using this is that it will generate icons for a variety of devices. That's nice if you anticipate your users will be saving the site to their phone icons.

Comment: Thanks! A similar icon generator website (created using Joomla) is http://iconifier.net. Full disclosure: I created iconifier.net. :)

Comment: Well, nice work!

Answer (score -1):

I had to comment out the following line from joomla template.

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

Now when reloading the homepage, the new favicon appeared, after which I un-commented the above line.

Comment: This will deactivate the output of the head, you shouldn't do this..

Comment: Yeah but only temporarily, once the browser updates it's cache we are going to "un-comment" that line. (re enable the above code).